# Custom fields in user model Django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-crispy-forms

I am using normal User model in Django to save my users. I would like to add first_name and last_name field, but I don't know how to extend my model and make it work. First and last name should be added in in register form (I use crispy forms).

***register view***

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()  # save user to database
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f"User {username} succesfully created! You can login now!")
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

***register form***

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserRegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password1'].label = "Hasło"
        self.fields['password2'].label = "Powtórz hasło"

    email = forms.EmailField()
    name = forms.CharField(
        label="Imię",
        required=True,
        max_length=30,
    )
    surname = forms.CharField(
        label="Nazwisko",
        required=True,
        max_length=30,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'name', 'surname']
        labels = {
            'username': 'Nazwa użytkownika',
        }
```

Comment: Django's `User` model already has `first_name` and `last_namee`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) already has a `first_name` and `last_name`, you can subclass the `UserCreationForm` and add fields for the `first_name` and `last_name`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserRegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password1'].label = 'Hasło'
        self.fields['password2'].label = 'Powtórz hasło'

    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField(
        label='Imię',
        required=True,
        max_length=30,
    )
    last_name = forms.CharField(
        label='Nazwisko',
        required=True,
        max_length=30,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name']
        labels = {
            'username': 'Nazwa użytkownika',
        }
```